# Вывести дату и время на страницк

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, легкий и элегантный способ вывести дату и время определенного часового пояса на странице сайта.
Сайт работает на bootstrap 3. 
Я так понимаю, нужен скрипт, отображающий время, но мне нужно брать конкретное время конкретного часового пояса, т.е. не с пк пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Пока ждал, сам нашел ответ:

```html
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date();
var month=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June",
"July","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
document.write(d.getDate()+ " " + month[d.getMonth()]
+ " " + d.getFullYear() + " г.");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если клиентский JS имеете ввиду, то сперва нужно узнать смещение (всё равно оно берётся с клиентского компьютера), а потом добавить разницу до целевого часового пояса:

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - offset + 120);
// отнимаем разницу offset, чтобы получить GMT время,
// а потом прибавляем разницу до нужного часового пояса
// в минутах, в моём примере, разница в 120 минут или 2 часа
console.log(d);
```

А если железно нужны точные данные, то берём при помощи PHP (или что там на сервере) из открытого сервиса и пробрасываем в JS.